# Movie where an astronaut finds a space module by looking his clock

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to find out the name of a movie (I think 80s) in which an astronaut is lost on the Moon (can't remember why) and needs to go to a different space module that happens to have a red light flashing over it.

In the last scene of the film, when the astronaut has already consumed all oxygen in his tank and thinks he's dead, he looks at his wrist clock and sees the reflection of the red light on it, and goes to the module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like [Countdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countdown_%281968_film%29) (1968), with James Caan and Robert Duvall.

I remember that the bulk of the movie was about training and technical development and the actual moon landing didn't happen until near the end. It was filmed with complete NASA cooperation and everything looked very authentic.

> *Everyone on Earth is nervously awaiting some news, but get none. Lee takes the Soviet flag from a dead cosmonaut and lays it out on a
>   nearby rock with his own American flag. With little air left and
>   nowhere to go, Lee spins the toy mouse his son gave him. It points
>   right, so he walks that direction. People on Earth are losing hope as
>   his time has run out. Lee looks at his watch to see that he has just
>   minutes of air left. A red glow on his arm catches his attention. It
>   is the locator beacon atop the shelter. Lee is last seen walking
>   towards the shelter.*

[image: Countdown]